# unity 初心者です

Tags: unity3d

blender・unityで製作し販売しようとunityでfbx化し新しいプロジェクトでで読み込み反映してるか確認したところ下記の画像のようになりました。わかる方教えていただけると幸いです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　折角ご質問いただいたところ申し訳ありませんが、こちらの質問には現状をどう直したいのかが書かれておらず、回答できません。質問を [edit] して、期待している挙動と実際の挙動のふたつをご説明いただけますでしょうか。